# Django - Defining ?next page from Admin

Tags: django, django-views

Is it possible to direct a user back to the previous page coming from the admin dashboard?

I have an "edit" button, and since the "users" who will be able to edit data are savvy enough, I'd rather just have this direct to a change page in admin.

Here is my link:

```
<td><a href="/admin/inv/lifesafety/{{life.pk}}/change/?next=/stores/{{store.pk}}" target="_blank"><i class="icon ion-md-create"></i></a></td>
```

Use of `?next=` from admin doesn't seem to work. For now I'm just having it opened in a different tab, but I'd like to at least know if there is a direct restriction, or if there's more to it when interacting with admin.

Here's an example:

- User goes to /stores/1617/
- User clicks "Edit"
- "Edit" directs them to /admin/inv/lifesafety/1617/change/?next=/stores/1617
- After User submits form, User is directed back to /stores/1617

Comment: I don't follow the flow you're trying to describe. Can you try to explain it in a bit more detail?

Comment: `?next=` chooses the next page. This doesn't work from admin pages. I would like it to work from admin pages.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. That next parameter is typically used when an unauthenticated user attempts to access a page that's protected by `login_required`. However, that doesn't seem to be what you're describing. Your case sounds more like you want to use the `Referer` header, but I'm not sure as I don't know the exact user flow.

Comment: I added a list to make it easier to get lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do this, but you can accomplish it another way by overriding the `response_change` method of the LifeSafety admin class.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class LifeSafetyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        next = request.GET.get('next')
        if next:
            return redirect(next)
        return super().response_change(request, obj)
```

Comment: Is there a more reusable way to do this application-wide? I would've expected it to be builtin, honestly. A little odd that they'd restrict the functionality strictly to auth.

Comment: You can subclass `ModelAdmin` and override `response_change`, then inherit from that class in every admin class for your project. Personally, I don't think this is something other people would need as Django does not recommend using the administration site for day-to-day operations. Plus the way to support it across your app is pretty simple.

Comment: Even if you weren't using admin for day-to-day operations, this would still be common functionality. Perform an action, return to the last page. I can definitely do it quite a few different ways, but nonetheless I'm shocked this is restricted to only work with login.

Comment: It does exist when you access the Create/Update page from within the admin. That's why there's Save, Save and continue editing and Save and add new. It accounts for all three possibilities.